# alphabet encryption program

Tags: c++, encryption

Hi I am working on an encryption program. The program should take a letter inputted by the user and replace it with the corresponding letter 11 places further down the alphabet. For example, if the user inputs "joe" the program should output "uzp".

My current code does this fine but it doesn't recognise spaces and the program should wrap-around the alphabet. So that'Y' becomes 'J' and  'Z' would become 'K' etc. Anyone know how I could fix this?

```
void encrypt(std::string &e);

int main() {

    string nameAttempt;

    cout << "Enter your name to be Encrypted: ";
         cin >> nameAttempt;


    cout << "Original string is: " << nameAttempt << endl;
         encrypt( nameAttempt );

    cout << "Encrypted string is: " << nameAttempt << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
}


void encrypt (std::string &e) {
     const char* tempCharArray = e.c_str();
     for( int i=0; i<e.size(); ++i )
     e[i] = tempCharArray[i]+11;  
     } //
```

Comment: Not important, but this cipher has a specific name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that you want to:**

- Replace lower-case letters with lower-case letters
- Replace upper-case letters with upper-case letters
- Leave spaces and any other non-alphabetic characters as is

---

```
void encrypt (std::string &e)
{
    int size = e.size();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        char c = e[i];
        if (('A' <= c && c <= 'Z'-11) || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z'-11))
            e[i] = c+11;
        else if ('Z'-11 < c && c <= 'Z')
            e[i] = c+11-'Z'+'A';
        else if ('z'-11 < c && c <= 'z')
            e[i] = c+11-'z'+'a';
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't wrap-around the alphabet though.  It also doesn't recognize spaces.

Comment: @user3420131: 1. It **does** wrap around the alphabet. 2. You did not mention in your question what you want to do with spaces, so I've assumed that you want to leave spaces as is (exactly as I mention at the beginning of the answer!!!).

Comment: why didn't you fold the last two conditions like the first two? Not that the compiler will care...

Comment: When I use this code when input r, for example, I get small heart as the output. And it stops encrypting anything after a space. Sorry wasn't trying to be rude

Comment: @user3420131: No problem, I made a small change in the code after posting it (and before you made that comment above), so perhaps you should just give it another try; it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
char _character='X';

int _value=static_cast<int>(_character);

if(_value!=32)//not space
{

    int _newValue=((_value+11)%90);

    (_newValue<65)?_newValue+=65:_newValue+=0;

    char _newCharacter=static_cast<char>(_newValue);
}
```